# Selecting a face - wonky in 2.83.2 with XRAY turned on

Tags: faces

I think I'm running 2.83.2 with factory presets. I have a giant model in Blender (a building) and it's ghosted from being selected. I HAVE XRAY TURNED ON. Next, I make a plane, STRETCH IT (big!), and am looking straight down on it from above. I go into edit mode, then face select mode, and click near the center of the plane, where the little dot it. The face gets selected. Dandy. Now, I click near the edge of the plane/face, and it does NOT select! the selection goes away. Turn XRAY off - and it works fine.

Is this a known bug?